# How do I set a default theme in multisite network

Tags: multisite

I have been trying to let all my users in my network to use the same theme as well as the main site but not working.

I have tried to use

```
Define ("default theme" , "classic") ;
```

But am seeing various errors and not working.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried enabling the theme from network admin? Visit /wp-admin/network/themes.php and "network enable" the themes you would like to allow access to.

You can set a default theme for new / existing sites on your network in wp-config.php Put this in your config file and change the theme name as desired.

```
define('WP_DEFAULT_THEME', 'classic');
```

[Network_Admin_Themes_Screen#Default_Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Network_Admin_Themes_Screen#Default_Theme)