# Wordpress multisite with separate domains

Tags: multisite, woocommerce-offtopic

I have been setting up a woocommerce wordpress site for a while now  on a sub domain and have successfully moved it to a main domain. I have enabled the multisite feature using the networking additions to the htaccess and wp_config.php

It works

However when I went to set up another site with a different mapped domain it said I could only have a subdomain as the site was already set up

Is there anyway around this?

WP 4.8

Answer (score 1):

Set it up using a subdomain/whatever is needed to get it working, then go to network admin and edit the site, and change its URL to the desired domain.

If you want more complex setups though, what you're trying to do is called domain mapping, and there are plugins from before WP Core supported this that are more flexible

Comment: I done exactly that and it appears to work although the new site has the theme twenty seventeen, its not activated in the network themes, so I am not sure what to you mean by more complicated setups

Comment: 2017 is the default, that's an unrelated issue, new sites aren't clones and still require setup. As for more complicated setups, these are things Core doesn't handle, e.g. sub-sub-directories won't work without a plugin, or having multiple TLD domains on a single site

Comment: I have two tld domains working in wordpress with out any plugins but only with the issue i have outlined above

Comment: the twentyseventeen theme? Just change the theme, WP doesn't know which theme to pick when you create a site so it uses 2017, to change that you have to set something in `wp-config.php`. However, that's a separate issue that you should ask as a separate question, if  my answer answers your question you should mark it as correct, comments are for clarifying things not asking new questions

Comment: also see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/208157/how-do-i-set-a-default-theme-in-multisite-network which I found as the second result after googling "multisite default theme" https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/208157/how-do-i-set-a-default-theme-in-multisite-network